# Installing Android on non-Android device questions

Tags: discussion, scope

So we seem to get questions every now and then from people who want to know about running Android on devices that originally came with some other OS (normally some flavour of WinMobile). Normally we aren't much more help to the asker than pointing them at some year-old thread on XDA, if we can even be that helpful.

Is there anything more we can do here, can we create a central "these non-Android phones can run Android" post, or is it not worth the effort?

There's also the occasional (how) can I install Android on my PC/laptop, should we also treat these the same?

Some example posts:

[Can I boot Android on the LG Arena KM 900?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/boot-android-on-the-lg-arena-km-900)
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/is-it-possible-to-install-android-on-samsung-omnia-pro-b7320
[HTC Tilt 2 -- possible to get Android on it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/768/htc-tilt-2-possible-to-get-android-on-it)
[Can I install Android on my HTC Touch HD?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4797/can-i-install-android-on-my-htc-touch-hd)
[(how) can I install android on an iphone 4?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/847/how-can-i-install-android-on-an-iphone-4)
[Installing Android on iPhone 3G](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/664/installing-android-on-iphone-3g)
[Is it possible to get Android on a Nokia e65?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/android-on-nokia-e65)
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/android-for-nokia-5230
[Is it possible to install Android on a PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/is-it-possible-to-install-android-on-a-pc)
[Trying google mobile android on my pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/trying-google-mobile-android-on-my-pc)
[Does Android 2.1+ support the ARM9 processor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/android-processor-compatibility-question)

Similar
[Android and other OS at the same time](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4278/android-and-other-os-at-the-same-time)

Comment: +1 on the central non-Android phones can run Android question; at least we would have somewhere to refer to when answering these sort of questions.

Comment: Now related: [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a generic question to cover this: [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

That way we can point people to that question and have a list of devices you can put Android on, rather than having tons of "No, drivers are hard etc." answers.

Comment: Nice one, now I'm waiting to see what will be the most outlandish device that someone asks about. Can't be long until our kitchen appliances meet the minimum specs...

Comment: @GAThrawn Haha yeah, seriously.  Once Roombas run Android we're all doomed.

Answer (score 8):

I would say it's on topic-ish, since the goal of the asker is to use and enjoy Android.

Isn't that an implicit shared goal of everyone here?

As long as it's asked in good faith and is of reasonable quality, I would allow it.

Comment: I agree. Trouble is that we don't seem to have anyone here that can answer those questions, except perhaps those that troll the xda forums, and the asker could do that just as well.

Comment: I'd rather let the community grow up to fill the need, than to try and change the need to fit the current state of the community.